# Graph dynamic connectivity

Tags: graphs, data-structures, connected-components

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph. I would like to maintain information about the connected components of this graph(I want to be able to tell in what component particular node is lying). The graph operations are the following (basically, everything except vertex deletion):

- Add vertex
- Add edge
- Delete edge

What are the state-of-the-art approaches to this problem? I know about various algorithms solving [dynamic connectivity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Fully_dynamic_connectivity) with $\mathcal{O}(\log^2(n))$(which is great complexity for me) update cost, but in my case, I want to add vertices too.

Comment: What do you mean with information? Is the requirement of your data structure that you can tell if two nodes are in the same CC or do you want to query in which CC a certain node ist? (CC = connected components)

Comment: I want to be able to tell in what component particular node is lying. The question is edited to clarify it.

Comment: When you add a vertex, does it always "appear" with degree 0 or can you add it with an initial neighbourhood (for free, without counting the edge additions operations)? If it's the former---which sounds more likely---I don't think adding vertices should change much (except for incrementing n) in the complexity of the updating procedures: basically isolated nodes are in their own (trivial, one node) tree in the forest datastructure. Right?

Comment: I think so too, but there are some minor changes in some algorithms. For example, in the [Level Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Fully_dynamic_connectivity) I need to provide the initial level of the vertex with the log of the upper bound of the graph size. I just wanted to be sure, that it won't break something subtle. I think I will write some prototype to test whether this modification is safe.